# Tomcat 8 - Allow Encoded Slashes on Azure

Tags: azure, tomcat, tomcat8

How can we set the "ALLOW_ENCODED_SLAHES" to true on an Azure/Tomcat 8 instance?

All information I found on this are impossible because we cannot modify the `server.xml`, `catalina.properties` or any other "root" configuration of the Tomcat. We can only modify your webapps files.

So how would we go about settings this property so the webapp works with it?

Comment: seems you need to use an IIS like  web.config, (resistance is futile) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32244868/azure-webapp-tomcat-8-configuration

Comment: @Sum1sAdmin I found that too, yet the linked articlle doesn't really explain anything related to how this web.config should look like or how it can set/change the apps settings or properties